# Import key on a given token with CNG

Tags: smartcard, cng

I've recently started fiddling with CNG to manage smartcards in our applications, and something remains quite unclear:
How do you import a key into a **given** smartcard ? It seems to me that the KSP just creates the key on the first card it sees.

Here's what I did:

- 2 smartcards are connected to my machine, from the same vendor.
- Said vendor implemented his own KSP, which appears when i list KSPs with NCryptEnumStorageProviders.
- Listing the keys available through the provider produces the following output:

  Got key: p11#958fb9080419db6e //Belongs to 1st smartcard 
   
  Got key: p11#9eaad58f1c3a73e5 //Belongs to 1st smartcard
  Got key: b6b99fb4-01c4-fa18-83db-0e2bb1c80476 //Belongs to 2nd smartcard

Now when i called NCryptCreatePersistedKey, the new key was generated on the 2nd card. No popup whatsoever asked me on which card i wanted to create this key.

What did i do wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Try to set smartcard reader explicitly in NCryptCreatePersistedKey(hProv, phKey, L"alg_id", L"\\\\.\\SmartCard Reader 0\\KeyName", 0, 0).

Comment: Well that does work. Accepting as an answer. On a side note, how do i somehow make use of reader names in CNG ? If my use-case is to identify a smartcard by a certificate contained in it, how do i retrieve the proper reader name ?

Comment: PS: post comment as an answer so that i may accept it

Comment: I suppose you can use one of this function SCardLocateCardsByATRW, SCardLocateCardsW.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardlocatecardsbyatrw

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardlocatecardsw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set smartcard reader explicitly in [NCryptCreatePersistedKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptcreatepersistedkey):

```
NCryptCreatePersistedKey(hProv, phKey, L"alg_id", L"\\\\.\\SmartCard Reader 0\\KeyName", 0, 0);
```